# Why we choose 2 large prime numbers in RSA Algorithm

Tags: security, rsa

I'm new in cryptographic, i'm trying to learn the **RSA** algorithm.

The RSA algorithm requires the selection of **two large prime numbers** to start the algorithm calculations.

Why we are forced to choose 2 large prime numbers ???
Is it motivated to get a large module number (n) ???

I googled a lot about it, I concluded that **it is not safe** to choose a small prime numbers, **isn't secure** ...

Can anybody explain why ???

Thank u in advance, BinaryMan.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography, not programming.

Comment: "I'm new in cryptographic" => STEP1: learn the name, which is cryptography. STEP2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)#Key_generation STEP3: if you have specific questions about implementation, ask here.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll take your tips seriously.

Comment: People have asked theoretical questions here before also instead of programming. He added security and rsa tags btw. The question is of rsa/cryptography so i guess it is rsa related right and not off topic.

Comment: @RahulGupta presence of older off-topic questions doesn't justify a new one in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RSA, the function used is based on factorization of prime numbers. First you need two prime numbers for generating a RSA key pair.

If you are able to factorize the public key and find these numbers, you will be able to find the private key.

**"It is not easy to factorize large composite numbers"**, that's why the length of the key is taken quite large so that the possibility of factorizing it can be removed

Comment: big thnks for you dear @Rahul !!! it helped a lot :) (Y)